# Call jQuery library with CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'd like to do something similar to this in CoffeeScript:

```
word_list =  [{ text: "cat", weight: 23 }, { text: "mouse", weight: 10 }, { text: "fox", weight: 5}, { text: "lion", weight: 4}, {  text: "giraffe",weight: 3}, {text: "zebra", weight: 2},{ text: "bat", weight: 20 }, { text: "rat", weight: 11 }, { text: "duck", weight: 4}, { text: "dinosaur", weight: 100}, {  text: "flamingo",weight: 50}, {text: "kangaroo", weight: 8},]

$(function() {
    $("#chart").jQCloud(word_list);
});
```

Would I make the call like this?

```
jQuery ->
    $("#chart").jQCloud(word_list);
```

Or do I need to do something like

```
$ ->
    $chart.jQcloud(word_list);
```

Comment: Would be the same `$("#chart").jQCloud(word_list);` in coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the first one. Or to make it exactly like the original:

```
$ ->
    $('#chart').jQCloud word_list
```

But `$` is the same thing as jQuery. Assuming you already created `$chart`, the second one’s valid too.

Comment: i see, how would i create chart?